# use of Include attribute effectively and dynamically

Tags: android, xml

can we reuse desired elements(instead of whole layout) of other xml via  attribute??
I want to use only some elements of XML1 in XML2 can i use it with the help of include function. for example i want to use all the elemnts of xml1 in xml2 but dont want background of xml1.
please reply soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using custom views...
It works very well usually and that's re-usable!

Edit : personnally, I use [Android Annotation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) -> look at the [custom view](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance%20custom%20views) page.

If you don't use AA, please look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

Comment: can you give me an example of reuse with  custom views by which i can use my these elements. i have 18-20 fields and i dont want to write them again or copy them i want a method to reuse them...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that sort of things. If you use an include tag, you include all the content.

I suggest you to think about your layouts include in a better way, so you can use include effectively.

Comment: thats what I am asking.Can i use the Id's of one's XML in other XML bcoz ID is fixed for every item in R so i wanna know if i use the id to view item on other XML will it work????